# Adaptive border top on <rect>

Tags: html, css

I have got different size on 'rect'. I don't can use 'border-top' option because it no working with rect. How I can do adaptive border top?

```css
rect {
stroke-dasharray: 60, 1000;
stroke-width: 5;
stroke: #000000;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <rect width="40" height="50" fill="#7cb5ec" class=""></rect>
  
</svg>

<svg width="100" height="100"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <rect width="60" height="75" fill="#7cb5ec" class=""></rect>
  
</svg>

<svg width="100" height="100"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <rect width="80" height="100" fill="#7cb5ec" class=""></rect>

</svg>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "adaptive"?

Comment: @ggdx one style border-top for all types of rect width

Comment: Basically you can't do this with standard CSS. You'd need JS.

Comment: if I use js I can change stroke-width when change vw, but this work bad